# Suddenly pgadmin doesn't allow me to select from a table

Tags: postgresql, permissions, pgadmin

I created a database, and created a user to access it via Python. Postgres user is an owner. I didn't access the database for a couple of weeks (before everything was working), and now when I want to implement a simple query I see:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for table project
SQL state: 42501
```

I have no idea what could happen on its own and how to fix it.

**Update**

It turned out that somehow the default user for this database was a user from another database. It became obvious when looked at the Grand Wizard... window (when started granting a privilege for a table, the Grantor is this wrong user). After disconnection and reconnection, the user became a proper one.

Comment: Log in as the user postgres and grant the privileges?

Comment: postgres is the owner, does it need additional privileges?

Comment: Your question seems to suggest that you created a user to access that table. Are you connecting to the database as that new user or as postgres?

Comment: I connected the database via pgAdmin where the postgres user is default always. I actually already found it was kinda glitch, see my update.

Comment: I like the idea of a "grand wizard" window. I want one of these too!